# Work with URL template parameter values in policy templates

Tags: azure-api-management

In API Management, how do you access URL template parameters through a policy?

In this instance, my operation is called `test`, the HTML verb is `GET`, and the URL template is as below -

> /test/{variable_name1}/{variable_name2}

I was under the impression that accessing the value of a parameter was as simple as `{variable_name1}`.  However, the example below does not set the variable "rowkey" as expected.  Rather it has a value of `{variable_name1}-{variable_name2}`.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <set-variable name="rowkey" value="{variable_name1}-{variable_name2}" />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <set-header name="Row-Key" exists-action="override">
            <value>@((string)context.Variables["rowkey"])</value>
        </set-header>
    </outbound>
</policies>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'd have to use expressions to achieve what you want, like:

```
<set-variable 
   name="rowkey" 
   value="@(context.Request.MatchedParameters["variable_name1"] + "-" + context.Request.MatchedParameters["variable_name2"])" />
```

or use string interpolation:

```
<set-variable 
   name="rowkey" 
   value="@($"{context.Request.MatchedParameters["variable_name1"]}-{context.Request.MatchedParameters["variable_name2"]}")" />
```

Comment: but from where i can set values for variable?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.

Comment: @Neo Create for example a GET operation like `/something/{myval}` - you can access the template parameter by `context.Request.MatchedParameters["myval"]`